# Read @PropertySource without Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a multi module Spring Boot project with the following structure:

- MyAppModule

  - src/main/java/Application.java
  - ...
- IntegrationTests

  - src/test/java/integrationTest.java

The *IntegrationTest* module is testing the *MyAppModule*. The *IntegrationTest* module does not have a main package. Therefore there is no Spring Application. It has just the test package.

Nevertheless I would like to read in the application.yaml for some properties but I'm not able to because the attributes are always null:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class IntegrationTest {

  @Value("${app.url}")
  private String appUrl;

}
```

Isn't it possible to use the `@Value` annotation without having a **Spring Application** (main with `SpringApplication.run` etc.)?

Comment: `@PropertySource` is only for `.properties` file not for loading `.yaml` files. Yes it is possible, no it isn't working (neither in Spring Boot) for YAML files.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just @ConfigurationProperties?

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class IntegrationTest {

 private String url;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Integration tests base package for component scanning in spring configuration.

```
@ComponentScan("basePackage1,basePackage2....etc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all responses. Solved it with the following code and a SpringBootApplication was necessary.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class IntegrationTest {

 @Value("${app.url}")
 private String url;

 }
```